# Xamarin Forms Xlabs

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to add a button which should be above the listView as same as how the whatsapp people have done and i want the same thing by using Xamarin Forms, i have tried doing with the xlab PopupLayout but i was unable to fix the position of the button as shown in the image the problem is with the different screen sizes and orientations..
So can any1 help me how to fix the location of the popup by using xlab popuplayout in xamarin forms and it should handle all the screen sizes and orientations.

[image: Add Button above the listView..]

Comment: You can use Grid. Add Button in Row 0 and ListView in Row 1

Comment: Actually its an floating button above the listview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this great post](https://alexdunn.org/2017/04/26/xamarin-controls-xamarin-forms-floatingactionbutton-including-ios/) by Alex Dunn. He implements a Floating Action Button (as it is called) on Android and iOS through Xamarin.Forms. It is basic, but you can extend on it yourself.

The gist is you create a control in your shared code, like this:

```
public partial class FloatingActionButton : Button
{
    public static BindableProperty ButtonColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ButtonColor), typeof(Color), typeof(FloatingActionButton), Color.Accent);
    public Color ButtonColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(ButtonColorProperty);
        }

        set
        {
               SetValue(ButtonColorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public FloatingActionButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now on Android implement a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), like this:

```
using FAB = Android.Support.Design.Widget.FloatingActionButton;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton), typeof(FloatingActionButtonRenderer))]
namespace SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class FloatingActionButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ViewRenderer<SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton, FAB>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            var fab = new FAB(Context);
            // set the bg
            fab.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Element.ButtonColor.ToAndroid());

            // set the icon
            var elementImage = Element.Image;
            var imageFile = elementImage?.File;

            if (imageFile != null)
            {
                fab.SetImageDrawable(Context.Resources.GetDrawable(imageFile));
            }
            fab.Click += Fab_Click;
            SetNativeControl(fab);

        }
        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            Control.BringToFront();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fab = (FAB)Control;
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.ButtonColor))
            {
                fab.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Element.ButtonColor.ToAndroid());
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.Image))
            {
                var elementImage = Element.Image;
                var imageFile = elementImage?.File;

                if (imageFile != null)
                {
                    fab.SetImageDrawable(Context.Resources.GetDrawable(imageFile));
                }
            }
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        }

        private void Fab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // proxy the click to the element
            ((IButtonController)Element).SendClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

And on iOS, like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton), typeof(FloatingActionButtonRenderer))]
namespace SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton.iOS.Renderers
{
    [Preserve]
    public class FloatingActionButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public static void InitRenderer()
        {
        }
        public FloatingActionButtonRenderer()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
                return;

            // remove text from button and set the width/height/radius
            Element.WidthRequest = 50;
            Element.HeightRequest = 50;
            Element.BorderRadius = 25;
            Element.BorderWidth = 0;
            Element.Text = null;

            // set background
            Control.BackgroundColor = ((SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton)Element).ButtonColor.ToUIColor();
        }
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            // add shadow
            Layer.ShadowRadius = 2.0f;
            Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
            Layer.ShadowOffset = new CGSize(1, 1);
            Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0.80f;
            Layer.ShadowPath = UIBezierPath.FromOval(Layer.Bounds).CGPath;
            Layer.MasksToBounds = false;

        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "ButtonColor")
            {
                Control.BackgroundColor = ((SuaveControls.Views.FloatingActionButton)Element).ButtonColor.ToUIColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should now be able to use your button from XAML and code as you like.
Here is the XAML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.FabExample" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.Views;assembly=SuaveControls.FloatingActionButton" x:Class="SuaveControls.FabExample.MainPage">
    <StackLayout Margin="32">
        <Label Text="This is a Floating Action Button!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

        <controls:FloatingActionButton x:Name="FAB" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Image="ic_add_white.png" ButtonColor="#03A9F4" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Please note that all credits for this go out to Alex. All his code for this is up [here](https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.FloatingActionButton). In the past I have also used the [NControls code](https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl.Controls) code to create something like this. And I'm sure there are more awesome libraries out there. However, have a good look at the support for libraries. If I'm not mistake the XLabs packages aren't supported anymore.